# Sending email error

Tags: java, javafx, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm having some problems with sending email in my JavaFX app. When I just tested sending email with a simple program (without GUI everything went fine and I was able to sent emails. However when I integrate in my app I'm getting this exception.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException

I added jar files (activation.jar, javax.mail.jar, smtp-1.6.0.jar). Since it worked when I firstly tested it I'm not having any idea how to fix it.

Here's the source code:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import dao.classes.KlientiHibernateDao;
import dao.interfaces.KlientiDao;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import models.Klienti;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import utils.HibernateUtil;
import utils.MyAlert;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Transport;
// import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EmailViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField emailTF;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField fjalekalimiTF;
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> marresiteCB;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField subjektiTF;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextArea mesazhiTA;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    private Alert alert;

    SceneChanger sc = new SceneChanger();

    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session;
    Transaction tx;
    KlientiDao kdao;

    public void butoniSend(ActionEvent event) {
        session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        kdao = new KlientiHibernateDao();
        kdao.setSession(session);

        List<Klienti> klientat = null;
        String[] marresit = null;

        try {
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            String user = emailTF.getText();
            String pass = fjalekalimiTF.getText();

            if (marresiteCB.getValue().startsWith("T")) {
                klientat = kdao.findAll();
                marresit = new String[klientat.size()];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < marresit.length; i++) {
                marresit[i] = klientat.get(i).getEmail();
            }


            String from = emailTF.getText();
            String subject = subjektiTF.getText();
            String messageText = mesazhiTA.getText();
            boolean sessionDebug = false;

            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

            java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] adresat = new InternetAddress[marresit.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < adresat.length; i++) {
                adresat[i] = new InternetAddress(marresit[i]);
            }

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, adresat);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(messageText);

            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, user, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            alert = MyAlert.returnConfirmationAlert("Alert", "Email shkoi me sukses!");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            alert = MyAlert.returnErrorAlert("Alert", e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        emailTF.setText("auto.x.prishtina@gmail.com");
        emailTF.setEditable(false);
        marresiteCB.getItems().addAll("Të gjithë klientët", "Klientët VIP");
        subjektiTF.setText("Përshëndetje i/e nderuar!");
        mesazhiTA.setText("Përshëndetje i/e nderuar!\n\n" + "Mesazhi i email-it" + "\n\nMe respekt,\nAuto X");

        try {
            File imgFile = new File("./src/imazhet/icons/email_icon.png");
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
            Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            imageView.setImage(image);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

When running is throwing exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 73 more
```

It works when I do this inside main method:

```
// Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginView.fxml"));
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EmailView.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        pS.setTitle("Login");
        pS.setScene(scene);
        pS.show();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03zwL.png)

But I do not want to run my app from that scene, I want to run from the login screen.

Here is the way how I change screens(stages):

```
public class SceneChanger {
    /*
        This method will accept the the title of the new scene, the .fxml file name
        for the view and the ActionEvent that triggered the change
    */
    public void changeScenes(ActionEvent event, String viewName, String title, boolean resizable) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(viewName));
        Parent parent = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        // Get the scene from the event that was passed in
        Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle(title);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(resizable);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

The error I think it's comming from here:

```
public void butoniEmailPromocional(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    sc.changeScenes(event, "EmailView.fxml", "Email promocional", true);
}
```

Comment: Are you running the program the same way? You could check, if moving the code to `main` method of the application class results in the same error (assuming the `Application` class is the entry point for your program). This is probably an issue with the classpath...

Comment: @fabian It would be sufficient to add `Class.forName("javax.mail.MessagingException");` as first statement in the **main()** method. When the jar is missing, then there will be the same exception.

Comment: I think the problem is with changing stages, which I do not actually understand why. But when in the main method I do this:                                                    
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EmailView.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        pS.setTitle("Login");
        pS.setScene(scene);
        pS.show();                                                                                                                            It works fine.

Comment: @Fabian - I edited the question, please view it again.

Comment: How are you building your code? What are you using for dependency management?

Comment: @Slaw - I'm not using maven or related technologies. I'm not using nothing at all. I don't know why I'm being able to send emails when I run from that view, and not when I press a button which triggers to change scenes.

Comment: IT'S WORKING FINE. It's interesting, it just needed firstly to run from email view, and then it could run even when the button requsted to go to email view from other part of the app.